# Convert TEXT to INT field (submit_date)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a field called `submit_date` which stores the value of a timestamp.

The field type is `text` - I want to convert it to `INT` - What is the safest way to do this?

Would converting to `INT` improve the performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way is to try ALTERing the datatype in a testing setup (i.e. not on live database). 
If this does not work, then you need to:

1. ALTER the table to add new INT UNSIGNED column
2. Copy data from the TEXT column to INT column using CAST()
3. Drop the old column, and change the name of new one. Create indexes as needed

Yes, it should in general be faster.

Comment: Are you able to cast directly to INT from a TEXT field in mysql? I ask only because I know in MSSQL you have to go text->varchar->int, it won't allow a direct cast.

Comment: Like this is ok? `ALTER TABLE  sales CHANGE  submit_date  submit_date INT( 12 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`

Comment: And don't forget to fix values that were not stored as int values first.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
CAST(submit_date AS UNSIGNED)
```

or

```
CONVERT(submit_date, UNSIGNED)
```

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html